# Angular Forms with a textarea

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm using angular forms in a dialog to collect strings. In the example below they are a `contact` and a `reason`. Everything works as expected when I use `input` tags, but I cannot get the formController to bind to a `textarea`. I'm having no luck with documentation. Am I missing something? a known workaround?

X.component.html

```html
  <form [formGroup]="myForm">
      <input formControlName="contact" placeholder="contact" required/>
      <textarea placeholder="reason" formControllerName="reason" required></textarea>
  </form>
```

X.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'X',
  templateUrl: 'X.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./X.component.scss']
})
export class XDialog{
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
      private fb: FormBuilder
  ){
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      contact: ['', Validators.required],
      reason: ['', Validators.required],
    });
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as `formControllerName`. It's `formControlName`. Voting to close for typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like an input a textarea makes use of the property `formControlName` instead of `formControllerName`.

```
<textarea placeholder="reason" formControlName="reason" required></textarea>
```

Here's a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-57597986

Comment: ...And then delete -- you still keep the rep, right?

Comment: I wouldn't delete it, as other people may have the same question. ;)

Comment: I added a stackblitz example.